# jQuery replace content from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to replace `{tree}` with variable `trees` from `desc` string, tried following but didn't work:

```
var trees = 12;    
var desc = "total {trees} left";
desc.replace('{trees}', trees);
```

Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: You need to assign output of `replace` to `desc`, besides that the code is fine. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp7ownvr/)

Comment: This script will work, it's possibile that the error is somewhere else? probably you are trying to retreive .text from an undefined variabile like `example.text` where `example` is undefined

Comment: works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/1yva4dts/